# Java making an arraylist of class and calling a method of that class

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, arraylist, identifier

So far I'm trying to make an `ArrayList` of objects that share the same method which I want to call in order of the `ArrayList`.

So far the code is like this

```
public class Shape extends Application {
   public void do(GraphicsContext canvas, int size, Color color){
     ;
   } 
}


public class Triangle extends Shape {
   @Override
   public void do(GraphicsContext canvas, int size, Color color){
      canvas.setFill(Color.WHITE);
      double[] xs = {60,80.0,50.0};
      double[] ys = {60,120.0,50.0};
      canvas.fillPolygon(xs,ys,3);
   }
}
```

And the main Class which launches automatically goes like this

```
public class Main {
    public void drawForegroundContent(GraphicContext canvas){
       ArrayList<Shape> shpes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
       Triangle t = new Triangle();
       shapes.add(t);
       shapes.add(t);

       for (Shape k : shapes){
          k.do(canvas,CoreColor.BLACK, 80);
       }
    }
}
```

However the error is `<identifier> expected` 
`k.do(canvas, CoreColor.BLACK, 80)`

Furthermore the it complains similarly on identifier on `void do`  of Shape-class. What exactly is wrong in this code?

Comment: If you are going to use only methods from List interface, then you should use it instead of ArrayList on the left side.  If you are using Java 7 or above you can take advantage of diamond operator on the right side: List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

If you are using java 10 or above you can use: var shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), `do` is a keyword (As in the context of a `do-while` loop). You need to name your method something else. As the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) say in regard to keywords:

> 50 character sequences, formed from ASCII letters, are reserved for use as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers

---

Also side note you have the arguments out of order when you call the method. You are passing `GraphicContext`, `Color`, `int`, when the method accepts `GraphicContext`, `int`, `Color`.